# Setting a windows form's screen position based on another form's current position

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am creating an application with multiple windows forms.  The main form is movable, and I want a confirmation window to flash based on where the main form is located.

For example, the main form opens, user drags it 200 points to the left.  How do I make sure the confirmation window, upon button-press, opens up exactly to the left of that window?

The built-in properties (center screen, center parent, etc.) don't provide this functionality.

I'm aware of these functions:

```
Form1.Left += 200
```

and

```
Dim frmAccounts as new Form()
Set FrmAccounts.DesktopLocation = new Point(100,100)
```

but neither of these take into consideration user dragging.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To keep the buddy glued to the main form, you have to use the main form's LocationChanged event to know when to move it.  And you have to position it before it is displayed, that's a bit tricky due the form possibly getting rescaled on a machine with a different DPI setting.  Best time to do it is when the buddy's Load event fires, it is rescaled by then.  Some sample code:

```
Public Class Form1
  Dim buddy As Form

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If buddy Is Nothing Then
      buddy = New Form2
      AddHandler buddy.Load, AddressOf MoveBuddy
      AddHandler Me.LocationChanged, AddressOf MoveBuddy
      AddHandler buddy.FormClosed, Sub() buddy = Nothing
      buddy.Show(Me)
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub MoveBuddy(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    buddy.Bounds = New Rectangle(Me.Left - buddy.Width, Me.Top, buddy.Width, buddy.Height)
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  It works great.  Any idea how I could tweak the code to work with forms with 0% opacity as well?  I have a script that fades in the form, then fades out.

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to get it to work.  Thanks again!